# How to Join 2 value in 1 table into 1 row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `log_attendance`

[image]

Output needed:

[image]

thank's for any help

Comment: is it possible to show two rows in two columns?

Comment: what's the exact schema of your table?

Comment: Can there be multiple results for each `emp_id`?  If so, lookup `gaps & islands`.  If not, lookup `min` and `max`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach to this, would be using `GROUP BY` clause by the `emp_id` column and then play with the aggregate methods `MAX()` and `MIN()` for get the desired result. Note that, for mapping to `NULL` values you will need to do an extra check, like this:

```
SELECT
    emp_id,
    MIN(tap_in) AS tap_in,
    IF(MIN(tap_in) = MAX(tap_in), NULL, MAX(tap_in)) AS tap_out
FROM
    log_attendance
GROUP BY
    emp_id
```

You can check it here also: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8MjNhfRkLueFjhYk67n6me/0)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use `GROUP BY` with `MIN` and `MAX` function to achieve your requirements.

```
SELECT emp_id,
       MIN(tap_in) AS tap_in,
       MAX(tap_in) tap_out
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY emp_id
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see the below simple query

```
SELECT empid,
   min([tap In]) [tap In] ,CASE WHEN  min([tap In])= max([tap In]) THEN NULL ELSE max([tap In]) END [tap out] 
FROM
    log_attendance 
 GROUP BY empid
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? `[tap In]` does not look like valid SQL

Comment: [tap In] is not a sql keyword it's the column name.

Comment: If that is meant to be the column name, why don't you write it as such? Currrently, your answer contains invalid SQL. Additionally, you should add an explanation to your answer such that others can see directly what is important to solve the problem

Comment: I am using SQL 2016 and i could not find any error.

Comment: The OP tagged the question with MySQL, so I don't think that a solution using SQL Server helps